# Stop SoundCloud HTML5 iframe player when clicking next slide

Tags: jquery, html, widget, soundcloud

--- **[EDIT**  ---

I had to use `getElementByID` for the below to work, however, is there a way of affecting *all* iframes within the carousel at once instead of individually adding IDs i.e. programmatically ? I'm generating the SoundCloud players within a CMS, so need a way in which I don't have to update the JS each time a new player is added...

Code edited below to reflect working solution.

--- **EDIT]**  ---

I'm trying to find a way of stopping SoundCloud from playing any songs currently playing *in various iframes* that are in a carousel when you go to the next slide, however, I'm having major problems doing so.

I've modified the the advice on here:

[Controlling Soundcloud HTML5 Widget Player with custom buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479747/controlling-soundcloud-html5-widget-player-with-custom-buttons)

And have referenced the API:

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget

However, when running my script I'm getting this error on the first line of `api.js` according to FireBug:

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentWindow' of undefined'
```

**Here's my code in the head of my page:**

```
<!-- Load SoundCloud API and controls -->
    <script src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* ****************************************************************** */
                    /* !SOUNDCLOUD WIDGET CONTROLLER */
    /* ****************************************************************** */ 
    // Get elements by ID
    var widget1 = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('sc-1'));
    var widget2 = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('sc-2'));
    widget1.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
        console.log('Ready...');
    });
    widget2.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
        console.log('Ready...');
    });
    $('#nx, #pr').click(function() {
        widget1.pause();
        widget2.pause();
    });
});
</script>
```

**Here's the HTML markup:**

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="slide">
        <h3>Intro</h3>
        <div class="desc"></div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <h3>Reel</h3>
        <div class="desc"></div>
        <span class="embed"><iframe width="100%" id="sc-1" height="315" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" src="#soundcloudurl"></iframe></span>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <h3>Another reel</h3>
        <div class="desc"></div>
        <span class="embed"><iframe width="100%" id="sc-2" height="315" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" src="#soundcloudurl"></iframe></span>
    </div>...
</div> <!-- End div#carousel -->
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cnav" id="pr"></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cnav" id="nx"></a>
```

Can anyone help me solve this please?

Thanks

Osu

Comment: Ok, I got it to work - code edited above. Seems I need to use ID's on the iframes in order for it to work. However, can anyone see a way to do this on each iframe within the carousel programmatically and using jQuery selectors? I'm generating a whole list of HTML5 SoundCloud players within a CMS for a client and don't want to have to update the JavaScript each time a new one is added....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really have to use IDs in order to interact with widgets, DOM node references are just as good.

```
var widgets = [];

// here's a selector that gets the widgets
$('.carousel iframe').each(function (index, iframe) {
  widgets.push(SC.Widget(iframe));
});

// at this point, `widgets` holds collection of all widgets in your carousel
// you could also get whatever iframes you like, first, last, first couple of them etc.
$('#nx, #pr').click(function() {
  for (var i = 0, len = widgets.length; i < len; i++) {
    widgets[i].pause();
  }
});
```