# Writing a for loop with to create multiple methods using arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, soundcloud

I'm trying to create a for loop that will reproduce the following functioning block of code, but in a much more attractive way. This is for use with the Soundcould widget API implementation found [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479747/controlling-soundcloud-html5-widget-player-with-custom-buttons)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('soundcloud_widget'));
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
  console.log('Ready...');
});}

$('#goTo5').click(function()  {widget.seekTo(300000);});
$('#goTo10').click(function() {widget.seekTo(600000);});
$('#goTo15').click(function() {widget.seekTo(900000);});
$('#goTo20').click(function() {widget.seekTo(1200000);});
$('#goTo25').click(function() {widget.seekTo(1500000);});
$('#goTo30').click(function() {widget.seekTo(1800000);});
$('#goTo35').click(function() {widget.seekTo(2100000);});
$('#goTo40').click(function() {widget.seekTo(2400000);});
$('#goTo45').click(function() {widget.seekTo(2700000);});
$('#goTo50').click(function() {widget.seekTo(3000000);});  */
});
```

This is my non working attempt at creating the loop with the arrays to write the lines:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('soundcloud_widget'));
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
  console.log('Ready...');
});

var goToId = [ "'#goTo5'", "'#goTo10'", "'#goTo15'", "'#goTo20'", '#goTo25', '#goTo30', '#goTo35', '#goTo40', '#goTo45', '#goTo50'];
var goToTime  = [ 300000, 600000, 900000, 1200000, 1500000, 1800000, 2100000, 2400000, 2700000, 300000];    

for (i=0, i<10, i++)
  {
    $(goToId[i]).click(function()
      {
        widget.seekTo(goToTime[i]);
      });
  }
});
```

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: Any reason not to use jquery? You could give all the buttons the same class and bind them in one go. You could then use the ordinal value of the id multiplied by 6000 to get the time.

Comment: I tested the JQuery method that @p.s.w.g suggested, but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written a closure over the variable `i`, but by the time the function executes `i` has incremented past the bounds of the array. You can get around this by create a function which generates a new function, and passing in the enclosed variables as parameters to the outer function, like this:

```
var clickFunc = function(seek) {
    return function() { widget.seekTo(seek); };
}
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    $(goToId[i]).click(clickFunc(goToTime[i]));
}
```

Also, I believe you'll have to remove either the single-quotes or the double-quotes in your `goToId` array:

```
var goToId = [ "#goTo5", "#goTo10", ... ];
// or
var goToId = [ '#goTo5', '#goTo10', ... ];
```

Or if you prefer, you can get rid of both your arrays entirely if you write your loop like this:

```
var clickFunc = function(id, seek) {
    $(id).click(function() { widget.seekTo(seek); });
}
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    clickFunc("#goTo" + (5*i), 300000 * i);
}
```

Or to implement the solution like what *net.uk.sweet* [hinted at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618125/writing-a-for-loop-with-to-create-multiple-methods-using-arrays/22618179#comment34441980_22618125), first assign a CSS class to all your `#goToN` elements, say `.goToButton` like this (I used `<a>` elements for demonstration, but the actual type of element you use isn't important):

```
<a id="goTo5" class="goToButton" href="#">5</a>
<a id="goTo10" class="goToButton" href="#">10</a>
<a id="goTo15" class="goToButton" href="#">15</a>
...
```

Then use the jQuery [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method:

```
$('.goToButton').each(function(i) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        widget.seekTo(300000 * (i+1));
    });
});
```

Note that this depends on the elements you're binding to being in the correct order within the document. If they are not in order, you may have to make adjustments to this script.

Comment: The items being passed at the beginning must be in '#something' format because of how the API interacts with the CSS elements on the page. I'm a little too rusty to understand how to add that in to what you have so gracefully written.

Comment: @RichardBellew I'm not sure what you're asking. If you mean the `"#goTo" + (i*5)` bit, that's used to produce CSS selectors like `#goTo5`, `#goTo10`, etc. up to `#goTo50` (notice the `i <= 10`).

Comment: the lines thr for loop generates create this:     `$(#goTo5).click(function()  {widget.seekTo(300000);});` but that does not work, it must be this    `$('#goTo5').click(function()  {widget.seekTo(300000);});`

Comment: @RichardBellew The quotes delimit a string literal. It's necessary when you need to directly create a string, but the quotes aren't actually part of the string. And when you simply want to refer to a string variable you don't need to wrap it in quotes. If your original code worked, then any of these solutions should work too.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I've tested the code and everything about it _should_ work, but for some reason it isn't. Here is my [example page](http://www.tradewelltax.com/test/post20140301.html). I've broken off the last section so that you can see it work by clicking the **50 minutes** button. Any idea on why it isn't working after seeing the full working/not working example?
**edit:** it all does not seem to be working in browser.

Comment: @RichardBellew well it seems to work for me. The only problem I see is that you can't scroll down far enough to put the 45 or 50 minute mark at the top of the window. This isn't a problem with your javascript, it's just that those marks are too close to the bottom of the page. You could just put a bunch of margin at the bottom if you really need that.

Comment: @RichardBellew Ahh, sorry. I thought you were just referring to the scrolling (I have sound muted on my PC so I wan't paying any attention to the audio). Now I see the issue. The commas in the for loop should be semicolons. See my updated answer.

Comment: It was probably working because I had jumped the gun on the post and had not yet posted the new edited version based on your suggestions.
[This one doesn't work](http://www.tradewelltax.com/test/post20140301.html) [This one does work.](http://www.tradewelltax.com/test/post20140301v2.html)

Comment: I made the changes you added in your answer edit, but that still isn't functioning. Everything looks good and I understand what your code does, but I don't understand why it isn't communicating to the player.

Comment: @RichardBellew The head of your `for` loop should be `for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)`, as I have in my answer.

Comment: It is exactly that. If it was not when you viewed it, then that is my mistake, but it is now and is still not functioning.

Comment: @RichardBellew Hmm, maybe I just needed to clear my cache. You've got an extra `});` after the for loop. Remove one of them and it should work.

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar. On monday's I lose my ability to count... when I was editing it before I uploaded it I thought to myself that it looked strangely like it had one too many closing brackets, but I didn't bother to count them because half of my brain is sleeping. I made that edit and it did seek, but all of them seek to 50:00 which would make it seem as if `var seek = 300000 * i` is being calculated as 300000 * 10 everytime?

Comment: @RichardBellew Whoops, silly mistake. I fell into the same trap you did. I've corrected all the solutions in my answer.

Comment: I see exactly what you mean. Thanks for the help. Great answer, not only did you provide a solution, but as we worked through it I genuinely understood why your solution works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Even if Javascript is a really large-minded language, you have to add the `var` prefix in your loop parameters :

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

**Edit #1 :**

Just saw you added some ' to your selectors :

```
"'#goTo5'"
```

Should be :

```
"#goTo5"
```

Or :

```
'#goTo5'
```

Comment: That was for testing purposes and I should have removed it before I posted. I works in none of the instances, be it "'item'", 'item', or "item". The string I am passing it works in the first example in 'item' format.